# How is the type check in printf implemented?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm writing a compiler and I want to implement the type check in `printf`:

```
printf("%f", i);



warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]   
  printf("%f", 1);
           ~~   ^~
           %d
```

As you can see, gcc knows what does %f mean, and try to warn me about the type mismatching.

So how I can implement this?

P.S. Is there any chance there are no mysteries, just a special rule gcc write for printf?

Comment: what would be an int divide by int give? What would a flow divide by int or vice versa give?

Comment: @SMA the warning are the same. For ease understanding I change the code.

Comment: why don't just check the `-Wformat` implementation in gcc's source code?

Comment: well gcc recognize printf and knows the first param is format thus it parses the format looking for % and then knows how many parameters are expected and of which type

Comment: One way would be to treat `printf` as a keyword rather than a generic function. Then, you'd parse the format string and create a list of the expected parameters. `%f`? `double`, `%d`? `int`, `%u`? `unsigned int`, etc. Then, once you've parsed the code, you can do a type check. Whether you do an implicit type conversion (with or without warning) or fail when something of the wrong type is provided is up to the language. (e.g. `printf("%s\n", 123)` works as well as `printf("%d\n", 123)` in Perl)

Comment: Note that parsing the format string is what `printf` does internally anyway. So if you're implementing `printf` yourself for this compler, you can share the same code that would operate at runtime, and just invoke it at compile-time instead to do a type check when the argument is a literal (or other compiler-supported constant).

Comment: @Leushenko, If you parse it at compile-time, then you don't need to parse it at run-time since the compiler could generate something equivalent to `print_int(i); print("\n");` for `printf("%d\n", i);`

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-flatten-function-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a combination of two special rules, described in the [documentation of `-Wformat`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wformat_003d).

The `printf` function is [built in](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins), which allows GCC both to optimize it and to warn about its misuse. About the specific case of `printf`, there's a note in the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-built-in-functions):

> In addition, when a function is recognized as a built-in function, GCC may use information about that function to warn about problems with calls to that function, or to generate more efficient code, even if the resulting code still contains calls to that function. For example, warnings are given with `-Wformat` for bad calls to `printf` when `printf` is built in and `strlen` is known not to modify global memory.

In addition, you can declare your own functions as printf-like for warning purposes with the [`format` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-Wformat-3).

```
__attribute__((__format__(__printf__, 2, 3))) /*printf-like function, the format string is parameter 2, the first element is parameter 3*/
int myprintf(int stuff, const char *format, ...);
```

With a built-in function, GCC tries to replace the function call by something more efficient. For `printf`, this generally means that when the format argument is a string literal, GCC replaces it by a series of calls to print the individual elements. For example it's likely to compile `printf("%d %s\n", x, s);` as if the program contained `__some_internal_function_to_print_a_dcimal_integer__(x); putc(' '); puts(s);`. While the compiler is performing this optimization, it'll notice any mismatch between the format string and the argument types and warn accordingly. If the function isn't built in but has a `format` attribute, you just get the warnings.

Comment: The compiler can compare the argument types to the conversion specifiers without regarding to optimization. In fact, [GCC warns even with optimization turned off](https://godbolt.org/z/hTt6eY). I expect this analysis is done in the front end while analyzing the source code and is not related to optimization.